# PHP - mysqldump doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to execute

```
exec('mysqldump -u user -pPASSWORD db1 tbl1 > /etc/table1.sql' ,$output, $return_var);
```

and also I have tried,

```
exec('mysqldump -u user -pPASSWORD db1 tbl1 > /etc/table1.sql');
```

but the **$output is empty**, and **$return_var is 2**

I have change apache user's permissions in file **/etc/sudoers**

```
#User privilege specification
www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Also the following is running on cmd

```
mysqldump -u user -pPASSWORD db1 tbl1 > /etc/table1.sql
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: `www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`—that's a *brilliant* idea!

Comment: While I upvoted eggyal's comment, just for your information its funny and sarcastic. **Never, ever, ever, ever, ever** give your webserver **root access**! Its a recipe for disaster, like giving a burglar a key to your home.

Comment: Okay i see and I will fix this, but i dont think that this is the reason that the command isn't running

Comment: Typically the apache process does not have a PATH environment variable set which is comparable to a "normal" user account. That would mean, that it is not able to find the `mysqldump` command. For a test have a try with the absolute path to the executable, probably `/usr/bin/mysqldump`.

Comment: Have you considered doing this with a cron job?

Comment: I tried with absulute path but nothing..

As regards for cron job, i dont want a sceduled task to run on a regular basis

Answer (score 0):

I would rather post this as a comment rather than an answer, but I suggest using `popen` as it might provide more helpful information why your command fails.

Full function signature:

`popen (string $command, string $mode)`

It works sorta like `fopen`, including the modes. In your case you will probably want to use `'r'` as your mode. The function returns a handle like `fopen` would do, so you can `fread` it for the data. Don't forget to `pclose` the hande after you're done!

To capture any error output (the function returns the handle even if command fails), add `2>&1` (leading space included) after your command. You can probably remove that afterwards, all it does is redirecting errors to the output.

**Source:**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php

Comment: That sounds like trying to convert the handle to a string (`print_r` or `var_dump`, maybe?). You will need to `fread()` some data or it won't be useful. You need to be like `$actual_output=fread($whatever_you_assigned_the_results of_popen_to, 1024)`. Try then `echo`ing that, and see what you get, okay?

Comment: I have already tried  `$read = fread($handle, 1024);` and `$read = fread($handle, 2096);` and the output is _resource id 3 resource_ **and** _resource id 2 resource_ respectively

Comment: Unfortunately, at the moment this is as far as my knowledge gets me. There was a thread somewhere, detailing an issue similar to yours, but they were trying to get data remotely. Here's the link, but I don't think it applies here: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21970324/PHP-MySQL-I-keep-getting-a-resource-id-3-error-with-fopen-and-fread.html

Comment: Quick thought passing by this again, is it `$read` you're trying to `echo`, or `$handle`?

Comment: Actually, I do this
 `$handle = popen('/usr/bin/mysqldump -h xxx -u user -pPASSWORD db1 tbl1 > /etc/table1.sql 2>&1', 'r'); echo "'$handle'; " . gettype($handle) . "\n"; $read = fread($handle, 1024); echo $read;`
and `echo $read` doesnt  print

Comment: Try `var_dump`ing it instead. Also, enable all warnings and errors with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` if you haven't done so already.